# Does Javascript cache in calculating math expression?

Tags: javascript, math, caching

I wondered which code will run faster:

```
i*i < number
```

or

```
i < Math.sqrt(number)
```

I used the following code

```
let number = 10000

console.time("i*i method");
for (let i = 0; i*i < number; i++) {}
console.timeEnd("i*i method");

console.time("math method");
for (let i = 0; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {}
console.timeEnd("math method");
```

with the following result:
`i*i method: 0.081ms math method: 0.012ms`

But then a question arose, whether that `Math.sqrt(number)` in the second 'for' cycle got cached and was used with each iteration or it was re-calculated every time. I am novice in JS and don't know how to check it. I am pretty sure that in Python and other languages that square root of 10,000 would've been calculated only once and cached. But is it so in JS?

Comment: Python doesn't cache the square root in `while i < math.sqrt(number):`. You're probably thinking of `for i in range(int(math.sqrt(number))):` but that's because `for i in <iterable>` only evaluates the iterable once.

Comment: There's nothing in the JS language specification that requires or prohibits this optimization. You'd have to check specific implementations to see if they do.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a benchmark at [jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me/bilgv2fonm/1). The difference between

```
for (let i = 0; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {}
```

and

```
let limit = Math.sqrt(number);
for (let i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {}
```

was negligible. So I think we can infer that the JS compiler is optimizing out the repeated calls to `Math.sqrt()`.

In comparison,

```
for (let i = 0; i*i < number; i++) {}
```

is 20% slower than the above.

However, this is implementation-dependent, so for best results you should cache the limit explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, but you pre-calculate "limit" in the second code block. The whole idea was to have the Math.sqrt within the "for" statement, to find out if it gets calculated every time. Any idea how to check it?

Comment: That's the point. If precalculating doesn't change the performence, it means that the compiler is only doing it once.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Of course, you did just that. I understand. Thank you very much.